# Electron forge stopped in complies renderer code when using electron ipc

Tags: webpack, electron, electron-forge

I am creating a new electron app but I met a problem I NEVER met

I used `import {ipcRenderer} from 'electron'` and used `ipcRenderer.send`, and it shows this error when Compiling Renderer Code.

In latest electron and electron forge, import electron and use it in **ANY** renderer code will cause error and terminate

I'm using React in electron, my previous project also used React+Electron, but it is okay to use electron module.

All things I can do is not working, including downgrade electron package.

Full logs:

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ electron-forge start
√ Checking your system
√ Locating Application
√ Preparing native dependencies
√ Compiling Main Process Code
√ Launch Dev Servers
√ Compiling Preload Scripts
√ Launching Application


Webpack Output Available: http://localhost:9000


\ Compiling Renderer Code

An unhandled rejection has occurred inside Forge:
[Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read] {
  errno: -4068,
  code: 'EISDIR',
  syscall: 'read'
}

Electron Forge was terminated. Location:
{}
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

I tried re install all packages, but it's NOT work.
Why & how to resolve?
Even I add a `target: 'node'` to webpack.renderer.config.json, oh the window can finally show, but ipcRender CANNOT send message

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'send' of undefined
    at onClick (TitleBar.tsx?3219:11)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?6ac8:3945)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?6ac8:3994)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?6ac8:4056)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js?6ac8:4070)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js?6ac8:8243)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js?6ac8:8275)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js?6ac8:8288)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js?6ac8:8299)
    at eval (react-dom.development.js?6ac8:8508)
```

---

WHY????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### tl;dr

Make webpack understand that electron should use `require` to import directly.

#### Solution

**This is a webpack issue.**

Webpack will pack all the packages that used into bundle. Because electron is a *super cool* package, webpack can **not** make it into bundle.

Config like this to make electron a commonjs2 module, make the statement from `import electron from 'electron` to `require('electron')` directly instead grab items from electron.

```js
// webpack.renderer.config.js
module.exports = {
  externals: {
    electron: 'commonjs2 electron',
  },
}
```

Comment: Great. Thanks you

Answer (score 2):

I met with the same problem still stuck on this

update: Use preload.js to access the main process' functions

Comment: Can you add more details? Thanks for it!

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. I'm using Webpack + React

After investigated, I think it's because the webpack bundle issue. We cannot even use the package `@electron/remote`

Here is my workaround. I created a function in the `preload.ts`

> Remember to use `import * as electron from 'electron';`

```
import * as electron from 'electron';

export function openDirectory(): void {
  const dialog = (electron as any).remote.dialog;
  console.log(
    dialog.showOpenDialog({ properties: ['openFile', 'multiSelections'] })
  );
}
```

[image]

Expose it by `contextBridge`

```
import { contextBridge } from 'electron';
import { getGitCommitLogs } from './core/git-api';
import { openDirectory } from './core/native-api';

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('getGitCommitLogs', getGitCommitLogs);
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('openDirectory', openDirectory);
```

[image]

Using it in the Renderer

[image]

Enable `enableRemoteModule`

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
    },
  });
```

[image]

> I have posted my source code and issue
> https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/2384

Comment: This is a great solution for that, but you have to declare all the methods in preload.ts. You can see my solution below (I read webpack documentation for a long time). Btw, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is using the `ContextBridge` API from `electron` for electron-forge [react+webpack](https://www.electronforge.io/guides/framework-integration/react) template

preload.js

```
import { ipcRenderer, contextBridge } from "electron";

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("electron", {
  notificationApi: {
    sendNotification(message) {
      ipcRenderer.send("notify", message);
    },
  },
  batteryApi: {},
  fileApi: {},
});
```

main.js

```
const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: false,
      contextIsolation: true,
      worldSafeExecuteJavaScript: true,
      preload: MAIN_WINDOW_PRELOAD_WEBPACK_ENTRY,
    },
 });

ipcMain.on("notify", (_, message) => {
   new Notification({ title: "Notification", body: message }).show();
});
```

package.json

```
 "plugins": [
    [
      "@electron-forge/plugin-webpack",
      {
        "mainConfig": "./webpack.main.config.js",
        "renderer": {
          "config": "./webpack.renderer.config.js",
          "entryPoints": [
            {
              "html": "./src/index.html",
              "js": "./src/renderer.js",
              "name": "main_window",
              "preload": {
                "js": "./src/preload.js"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
```

app.jsx

```
import * as React from "react";
import * as ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    electron.notificationApi.sendNotification("Finally!");
  }
  render() {
    return <h1>contextBridge</h1>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I found a better way after spend a lot of time on reading webpack documentation. Check it below, it might solve your problem too!